# PHP : Store SESSION Permanent

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I try to use session for manage selected cities. I give function to user for select their city and it would be selected on all page, but my current code only work for one page. function is like if User select city "Vadodara" then all page display selected city as "Vadodara" and If He/ She change it to "New York" then all page display selected city as "New York", its work but only of one page. Here is my PHP code. **session_start();** already added

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['location']))
{
    $_SESSION['location'] = $_REQUEST['location'];
    $location = $_SESSION['location'];
}
else
{
    $location = "All";
    $_SESSION['location'] = $location;
}
```

?>

Comment: I don't think you would loose session from a page to page, you can though store this information in cookie or localstorage using html5 api

Comment: add session_start() at the very beginning of the code after <?php

Comment: what you using on other page $location or session

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - And show the errors if there are some present.

Comment: @RakeshSharma this code in under navigation file and I include it in every page and I user $location for display

Comment: @Darren no, there is no error, you can see my code @ www.humdesis.com try there, change location and navigate to another page. its display "all"

Comment: The problem with your code is the following: as soon as no "location" GET or POST parameter is found, you reset the location to "All" and store that value in your session. I'll post an updated version of your code as a separate answer.

Comment: what to need there $_SESSION['location'] use $_SESSION['location'] rather $location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your above example you keep on resetting the location. Try this version instead:

```
<?php
session_start();

$location= isset($_SESSION['location']) ? $_SESSION['location'] : 'All';

// if location has been changed, store it in session and update location variable
if(isset($_REQUEST['location']))
{
  $_SESSION['location'] = $_REQUEST['location'];
  $location = $_SESSION['location'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start();` on top of all other pages you want to load your session